# Can we use sshfs or NFS for LVM?

Tags: nfs, lvm, sshfs

I want to create LVM using sshfs or NFS. Is it possible at all? I tried searching over web but did not find anything. Forgive me if this question is wrong for this community.

Comment: Even if you were able to get this to work, me thinks it would perform terribly.

Comment: It's not the wrong community *per se*, but this looks very [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  Instead of asking us how/whether one can do something that is a Bad Idea, how about you tell us what you're actually trying to do, and we might be able to help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Is there a way to do something like LVM over NFS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/89269/is-there-a-way-to-do-something-like-lvm-over-nfs?rq=1) it is possible.

Sensible is another matter: as noted in the answer to that question, if NFS (and/or the network) has an issue at any point, there is a strong chance your LVM will get corrupted.

I would have to assume that same risk applies (possibly more so) to SSHFS.

A possibly less brittle solution might be to have LVM underpinning your NFS exports - that sounds less risky, but without knowing your use case, I don't know if it would do what you wanted it to.

**Updated** I would have to agree with @[MadHatter](https://serverfault.com/users/55514/madhatter) this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), then.

In this case, it does sound like using LVM on your NFS server, and then exporting the LVM volume using NFS would be functionally equivalent, while avoiding (some of) the potential for corruption.

I suppose sharding could be mentioned here - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541421/mysql-sharding-approaches for discussion about that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would rather not do it. I was trying to a very large partition for a big SQL database with smaller hard drives.